# Iterating over a for loop in C++ and comparing the iterator to a negative number. Can an int store an unsigned int?

Tags: c++, integer, unsigned-integer

I want to:

1. Store a default index value of "-1".  If I finish iterating through a vector (using a for loop) and the index value is still "-1", I know none of the values checked by my for loop are matches.
2. If a suitable value is found, update the index value to match the index of a value in the vector I'm iterating through.

Example:

```
int index = -1;
for (int i; i < vector.size(); i++){
    if (vector[i] == 1) {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

However, I always get a warning about "comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions" from `for (int i; i < vector.size(); i++)`.  Unfortunately, I can't just use `unsigned integer index = -1`, since unsigned integers can't store negative values.  **Is it safe to store an `unsigned int i` value in `int index`, or do I need to find a different method of comparison?**  In this case, I would change the for loop to `for (unsigned int i; i < vector.size(); i++)`, but leave the rest of the code the same.

I could use a separate boolean variable, but it just seems more cluttered to use the extra variable every time I run into this scenario.  It would looks something like this:

```
bool found = false;
unsigned int index = -1;
for (unsigned int i; i < vector.size(); i++){
    if (vector[i] == 1) {
        index = i;
        bool = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use iterator instead and as a bonus you do not have to write a loop at all:

```
auto it = std::find( vector.begin(), vector.end(), 1 );
if( it == vector.end() ) {
    ... // not found
}
```

you can use iterator with explicit loop though if you prefer.

```
auto it = vector.begin();
for( ; it != vector.end(); ++it ) {
     if( *it == 1 ) break;
}

if( it == vector.end() ) {
    ... // not found
}
auto index = std::distance( vector.begin(), it );
```

Comment: This is the proper way to solve the problem (determining if an element exists in a Vector and, if it does, getting the index) -- but it doesn't answer the original question: Can you store an `unsigned int` into an `int`. To which the answer is "yes, but you might get a runtime exception if you encounter integer overflow"

Comment: @stevendesu question on subject does not much body (for example boolean flag does not allow to store either) so I am not sure which question is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a special value:

```
unsigned int index = (unsigned int)-1;
for (unsigned int i; i < vector.size(); i++){
    if (vector[i] == 1) {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

The compiler will set `(unsigned int)-1` as the largest value that fits in an unsigned int, which for a 32 bit representation is 4,294,967,295

Answer (score 1):

I recommend adding a function:

```
bool contains(std::vector<int> const& vec, int item);
```

Then, the client code can be simplified to:

```
if ( contains(vector, 1) )
{
   ...
}
else
{
   ...
}
```

The implementation of `contains` can take several forms.

1. Use an index-based `for` loop.
2. Use a range-`for` loop.
3. Use `std::find`.

None of them requires you to store a sentinel index value.

#### Using index-based `for` loop

```
bool contains(std::vector<int> const& vector, int item)
{
   for (size_t i = 0; i < vector.size(), ++i )
   {
      if ( vector[i] == item )
      {
         return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

#### Using range-`for` loop

```
bool contains(std::vector<int> const& vector, int item)
{
   for (auto x : vector)
   {
      if ( x == item )
      {
         return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

#### Using `std::find`

```
bool contains(std::vector<int> const& vector, int item)
{
   return (std::find(vector.begin(), vector.end(), item) != vector.end());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could operate in `size_t` no need to switch to `int`. This way it is guaranteed your index will be compatible with the size of your vector. Also if you still want to compare to -1, you can.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 0,2,3,4 };

    size_t index = -1;

    for (size_t i = 0, n = v.size(); i < n; ++i)
    {
        if (v[i] == 1)
        {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (static_cast<int>(index) == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "not found" << std::endl;
    }
    else
        std::cout << index << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `size_t` for addressing into `std::vector`s. Think of the day someone will pass a vector with exactly 2^64 entries to your function.

Personnaly, I find the boolean much cleaner as it makes the intent explicit.

Comment: @Slava's answer is better, but if you ever need to random access your vector, use a size_t. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your first approach is OK for small numbers.

Just use static cast, to directly say to compiler that you are doing that purposely

```
    index = static_cast<int>(i);
```

and in the loop use `unsigned int`